# Откуда появляется +1?

Tags: обсуждение

Уже третий раз за последние пару недель происходит следующее. Есть вопрос. Пишу ответ. Отправляю. Загружается страница с моим ответом - и у него УЖЕ есть один голос.

Сомневаюсь, что кто-то за ту секунду, пока у меня загружалась страница, успел плюсануть ответ - да за это время ответ даже прочитать не успеешь... тогда что это?

PS. Последний такой "плюсанутый" ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/720240/229437

Comment: удаленный голос против :-), а не, это про другой +1. В этом случае просто кто-то проходит и плюсует :-) это нормально

Comment: Возможно кто-то в момент отправки просматривал вопрос, появилась надпись, что появился новый ответ, он нажимает на нее, читает ответ, плюсует. Ответ не длинный, поэтому в принципе по времени это все может занять пару секунд.

Comment: @insolor, не, есть некоторые кто просто плюс ставит сразу

Comment: Согласно тому, что я вижу, голос за поставлен реальным участником.

Comment: [Бывало такое и раньше.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35167202#35167202)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky реальный участник - это обладатель знака "не робот"? Кстати, почему-то не могу найти его у нас в списке знаков. Раньше ведь был!

Comment: @alexolut нет, без знака, но все же, видимо, не менее реальный, чем мы с вами.

Comment: Я в этой ситуации когда-то был с другой стороны: открыл вопрос, там данный секунд пять назад ответ, я в целом вижу что он верен и плюсую.

Comment: @Grundy кстати, тоже первым делом подумал про откат после удаления!